# I couldn't add data from my form inputs to the Firestore collection and I can't find out what is the problem here

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, user-input

```
<body>
    <div class="wrap-content5">
        <label for="itiName">Very Nice:</label><br><br>
        <form id="add-location-form">
            <input type="text" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Location Name"><br>
            <input type="text" id="inputLat" name="inputLat" placeholder="Latitude">
            <input type="text" id="inputLong" name="inputLong" placeholder="Longitude"><br>
            <button id="addLocation-btn" onclick="storeData()">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I try to get the inputs and add it to the firestore collection here.
Firestore collection name: location.
I also leave the document id blank to allow it to generate automatically.

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

    <script>
        // From Firebase Project settings
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "",
            authDomain: "",
            databaseURL: "",
            projectId: "",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: "",
            appId: "",
            measurementId: ""
        };

        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const db = firebase.firestore();

    </script>

    <script>
        // app.js file for function storeData() from button onclick in html form
        function storeData() {

            var inputName = document.getElementById('inputName').value;
            var inputLat = document.getElementById('inputLat').value;
            var inputLong = document.getElementById('inputLong').value;

            db.collection('location').doc().set({
                name: inputName,
                lat: inputLat,
                long: inputLong
            })
            .then(function(docRef) {
                console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
               console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
            });
        }
    </script>
   
</body> 
</html>
```

Firestore collection should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf2la.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem most probably comes from the fact that your form is submitted before the Firebase `set()` method is triggered.

As a matter of fact, you declare your button as follows:

```
<form id="add-location-form">
    // ...
    <button id="addLocation-btn" onclick="storeData()">Add</button>
</form>
```

i.e. **without** any `type` attribute.

As detailed in the [W3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) on button types, "the missing value default is the Submit Button state" and "if the type attribute is in the Submit Button state, the element is specifically a **submit** button".

So, if you add a button type to your button, as follows, it should solve your problem.

```
<button type="button" id="addLocation-btn" onclick="storeData()">Add</button>
```